# Pandas chain method drop/dropna with reset_index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, reset

I have this problem that I can't figure out why its happening and I'd love to gain some more knowledge.

So my problems is that I am trying to chain methods with drop or dropna and reset_index but for some reason when I mention that `inplace=True` parameter for reset_index it does not work.

When I use this:

```py
df.dropna(how='all',axis=(0,1)).reset_index(drop=True)
df.drop(index=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

And save it into a variable it seems to be working. But when I use this:

```py
df.dropna(how='all',axis=(0,1)).reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
df.drop(index=0).reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

And later print df.head() it does not seem to be working.

Not sure what I am missing here but I'd love to understand better about the method chaining.

Thanks!!

Comment: A pandas method called with `inplace=True` returns None, which is then assigned to whatever variable is on the left side of `=`. You can't combine `inplace=True` with method chaining: https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining.html

Comment: Thank you for you answer. So even if the inplace=True is given in the last function its not possible? I can see why not now, because first function returns dataframe and the second work on that specific dataframe which is not saved anywhere. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To understand why method chaining in `pandas` does not work with `inplace = True` consider what happens under the hood without method chaining:

1. A copy of the dataframe is created
2. Method computations are done
3. Result is assigned back to the original dataframe
4. Return type is None

When `inplace = False` on the other hand, after going through `1 and 2`, the method returns a copy of the dataframe which should be assigned manually.

In case you set `inplace = True` in between a method chain e.g:

`df.method1().method2(inplace = True).method3()`

the next method i.e. `method3` will fail upon receiving an object of type `None`.

Now, you might think that if this is the case, we might be better off setting it in the end:

`df.method1().method2(inplace=True)`

The catch however is; each method in the chain returns a copy of the dataframe for the next method, which in turn creates another copy of that copy. Here, method2 operates on a copy (`copy2`) of method1's copy (`copy1`), does some computations, saves `copy2` back to `copy1` and returns with `None` while all the intermediate copies are destroyed.

This is why one should avoid using `inplace = True` while chaining methods together.